# FormData how to get or set boundary in multipart/form-data - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multipartform-data

I have a mini app, where I have to post a form data to an endpoint from browser.

This is my post:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('blobImage', blob, 'imagem' + (new Date()).getTime());

return $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: api + '/url',
  data: formData,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
})
```

Boundaries seems to be added by formData to the parameter, however, I cannot get it to send in the header, how should I done?

Comment: You are missing closing quote at `'multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Well, seems that the headers ContentType should be undefined, in order to add the correct boundaries

Answer (score 6):

The correct way was to *not* set `Content-Type` header.

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('blobImage', blob, 'imagem' + (new Date()).getTime());

return $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: api + '/url',
  data: formData,
  // headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
})
```

Other headers (like `Authorization` are fine). Here is an Example:

```js
import { http } from '@angular/common/http'

function sendPostData(form: FormData) {
  const url = `https://post-url-example.com/submit`;
  const options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer auth-token`
    })
  };

  return http.post(url, form, options);
}
```

Further adding [Pablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40362274/4562090).

When http request body has a `FormData` type, angular will defer `Content-Type` header assignment to browser. `detectContentTypeHeader()` will return `null` on `FormData` request body and angular won`t set request header.

This was on `@angular/commons/http/src/xhr.ts` module.

```js
  // Auto-detect the Content-Type header if one isn't present already.
  if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
    const detectedType = req.detectContentTypeHeader();
    // Sometimes Content-Type detection fails.
    if (detectedType !== null) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', detectedType);
    }
  }
```

Content-Type detection based on request body:

```js
  detectContentTypeHeader(): string|null {
    // An empty body has no content type.
    if (this.body === null) {
      return null;
    }
    // FormData bodies rely on the browser's content type assignment.
    if (isFormData(this.body)) {
      return null;
    }
    // Blobs usually have their own content type. If it doesn't, then
    // no type can be inferred.
    if (isBlob(this.body)) {
      return this.body.type || null;
    }
    // Array buffers have unknown contents and thus no type can be inferred.
    if (isArrayBuffer(this.body)) {
      return null;
    }
    // Technically, strings could be a form of JSON data, but it's safe enough
    // to assume they're plain strings.
    if (typeof this.body === 'string') {
      return 'text/plain';
    }
    // `HttpUrlEncodedParams` has its own content-type.
    if (this.body instanceof HttpParams) {
      return 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
    }
    // Arrays, objects, and numbers will be encoded as JSON.
    if (typeof this.body === 'object' || typeof this.body === 'number' ||
        Array.isArray(this.body)) {
      return 'application/json';
    }
    // No type could be inferred.
    return null;
  }
```

Source:

- [@angular/common/http/src/xhr.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3b0b7d22109c79b4dceb4ae069c3927894cf1bd6/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L105)
- [@angular/common/http/src/request.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3b0b7d22109c79b4dceb4ae069c3927894cf1bd6/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L269)

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else is struggling with this... If you are submitting FormDate then the browser should be setting the content-type for you. To get this working i just set the enctype header to for multipart/form-data

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
return this.http.post(path, formData, { headers: headers })
```

I also had a HttpInterceptor which was setting the content-type so only set this when the enctype was not set

```
if (!req.headers.has('enctype')) {
headersConfig['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip!! I was trying to solve a problem for 3 days and I found the reason because of your comment.