# How to receive $ FILES in PHP from Ionic?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ionic-framework

I'm using FormData to send a file from ionic with angular to PHP, but in the PHP backend when you make var dump $_FILES appear empty.

This is my code in .ts:

```
  file: File;
  changeListener($event): void {
    this.file = $event.target.files[0];
    console.info(this.file); //First console info
    const formData = new FormData();
    const blobFile = new Blob([this.file], { type: this.file.type });

    formData.append("file", blobFile, "filename");
 
    this.myService.testing(formData).subscribe( resp => {
        
      },(error)=>{
       
        console.info(error);
        
        
      })  

  }
```

In the service:

```
testing(data) {

return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})

}
```

The PHP Backed :

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); // this shows me the contents of the file
var_dump($_FILES); // returns an empty array
```

So, what's my mistake? Am I sending badly from Ionic or am I getting bad in PHP ?

I'm using codeigniter 3

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried making the POST request with `multipart/form-data` content type?

Comment: Yes. I already did too, but still $ FILES is still empty

Comment: Hmm, what structure does your `php://input` show?

Comment: $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");    var_dump($postdata); Shows me the contents of the file (txt) but I need to upload the file to a folder

Comment: Try calling the post() like this (without header information): `this.http.post(url, body)`. The browser will set the multipart/form-data automatically and will define the `boundary` as well. Just setting the header multipar/form-data and not setting the boundary will not work. See this for more info about boundary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351429/formdata-how-to-get-or-set-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-angular

Comment: @francisco neto  is correct!.  I deleted the header and now if it works.  thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FormData how to get or set boundary in multipart/form-data - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351429/formdata-how-to-get-or-set-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-angular)